# Html encode variable in quoted string

Tags: php, html-encode, php-5.4

In PHP5.4, is it possible to html encode ([using htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)) a variable being used in a quoted string?

For instance, is it possible to format the following so that `$title` is automatically encoded by PHP?

```
echo "<h1>$title</h1>";
```

In ASP.NET (my normal development technology) I can write an inline code block like `<%=title%>`, but if I want to html encode `title` then all I have to do is write the block like `<%:title%>`.

I realise the following are ways to do it, but they are "messy" and less readable in comparison...

```
echo '<h1>' . htmlspecialchars($title) . '</h1>';
printf('<h1>%s</h1>', htmlspecialchars($title));
```

Comment: How do you mean *automatically* ? Just encode it and assign it

Comment: Good point @Rizier, I guess I've not made that clear... will update the question

Comment: I don't think this is possible in PHP to apply automatically a function to all variables which you print

Comment: That was my assumption @Rizier - I'm getting my teeth back into PHP for the first time in years, so am not up to speed with all the latest features of PHP5

Comment: No. You can't have htmlspecialchars() automatically applied to variables in PHP. But, if you use any MVC framework, for example CI, Yii, it is not hard to override view's classes that will do it when you pass variables from controller to view. Another solution - wrap function with you own function, for example with "hm" as name, and then write hm($var) - it will shorter and quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest and ASP.NET like way is:
    `<h1><?= htmlspecialchars($title) ?></h1>`